# Second derivative Test becomes zero

Tags: self-learning, maxima-minima

Consider the domain $D = \{ (,) ∈ ℝ^2: ≤  \}$ and the function $ℎ:  → ℝ$ defined by $ℎ((,)) = ( −2)^4 +(−1)^4$, $(,) ∈ $. 
Find the minimum value of $h$ in the domain $D$:
a) $1/2$
b) $1/4$
c) $1/8$
d) $1/16$

**My work:**

$f'(x) = 4(x-2)^3$
$f'(y) = 4(y-1)^3$
$f''(x) = 12(x-2)^2$
f_{xy} = $4(y-1)^3$  (partial derivative of $x,y$)
Critical points are $x = 2$ and $y = 1$,
Performing second derivative test with $x = 2$ and $y = 1$ ***I get zero*** ,
How do I proceed and where have I gone wrong?   kindly help .
The answer is Option **C: 1/8**

Comment: The domain does not include $(x,y)=(2,1)$.

Comment: How do I proceed then ? Can you help ? @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(2,1)$ is not in the domain of $D$ of $h$, we have $\operatorname{grad}h(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ for all $(x,y) \in D$. Thus investigate the function $h$ on $ \partial D=\{(x,y): x=y\}$.

Hence consider $f(x):=(x-2)^4+(x-1)^4$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! should I try finding critical points to this by differentiating and equating to zero ?

Comment: Yes, find $x_0$ with $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: This is what I have done , I differentiated it and got $4(x-2)^3 + 4(x-1)^3$ ,After expanding and equating to zero I get $2x^3 -9x^2 +15x -9 = 0$ ,I am stuck here and not able to solve it further .

Comment: I tried to solve but wasn't able to get an answer thats in the option

Comment: From $4(x-2)^3 + 4(x-1)^3=0$ we get $(x-2)^3=-(x-1)^3$, hence $|x-2|=|x-1|$, thus $x=3/2$.